# Sending Email from ASP.Net, From address not shown correctly to the recipient

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am facing an issue when I send email from my ASP.Net application. There is no error in sending the mail, but when the email is received by the recipient, the from email address is shown as the username of network credential.

In my case, I am using `smtp.gmail.com` as smtp host and the user name and password are also of my gmail account.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@mydomain.com", "Enquiry");
mail.To.Add("munjal.pandya@yahoo.com");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "Registration";
mail.Body = "Some Text";
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
//smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "<my gmail pwd>");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
//smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

The `From` address shown to the recipient is `xyz@gmail.com`. But actually it should be `abc@mydomain.com`.

If anyone have an idea regarding this issue, please let me know.

Comment: use you abc@mydomain.com. credentials instead of gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the coding issue, just add email abc@mydomain.com as additional address in gmail and verify it.

In gmail interface: Settings -> Accounts -> Send letters as ...

Answer (score 1):

With Gmail, it is not possible to spoof the sender. Gmail always shows the actual "sender", not the spoofed one.

You might be able to try it with other email providers, but Gmail are so strict in protecting their users.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response. The email address needed to be verified by gmail from the account settings.

Please find my blog post for the same describing it in detail, the steps to be followed:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/send-email-from-aspnet-using-gmail-as.html

before following all the above steps, you need to authenticate your gmail account to allow access to your application and also the devices. Please check all the steps for account authentication at the following link:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/11/allow-account-access-while-sending.html