# sending mail asp.net using google smtp service

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

before asking i search some possible solution in this site.
I found this [Solution that I implemented in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660537/sending-email-from-asp-net-from-address-not-shown-correctly-to-the-recipient)
But I have an error: when I send a mail with my code (in localhost) I obtain "Invalid Handler" but username and password are correct. Someone can help me?thanks

This is the cdoce

```
private SendGmail(){
   try{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "Enquiry");
    mail.To.Add(TextBox_mail.Text.ToString());
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Subject = "Test";
    mail.Body = "Some Text";
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    }
        catch (Exception errore)
    {
    elenco_errori.Visible = true;
    elenco_errori.InnerText = errore.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your complete error

Comment: the message that I find in the exception (in exception.Message) is: invalid handler

Comment: Post the code you wrote please

Comment: I added the code in the message

Comment: @P_R see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189098/why-i-am-not-receiving-e-mail-from-my-mvc-4-razor-site/20189463#20189463) on a different (but similar) question.

Comment: It's the same..It doesn't work with the port 465

Comment: @P_R can you post the *exact* exception then...

Comment: it is this:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Handle non valido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question
in Application Start, in global.asax I added this code

```
public void Application_Start() {
  System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
  System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
}
```